# 'RCT3DModel-Swift.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, 3d

I am working with 'react-native-3d-model-view'. Stuck at **'RCT3DModel-Swift.h' file not found**. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you these steps in your project: https://github.com/BonnierNews/react-native-3d-model-view#swift ?

Comment: I tried to follow the link 'Xcode Build Settings' provided in the documentation part. I am using Xcode 13. I followed that link but the listed steps differ.

Comment: any solution for this problem